# Нахождение наиболее часто встречающегося элемента в массиве

Tags: c, алгоритм

Недавно надо было сделать задачу, в которой одной из подзадач являлось нахождение наиболее часто встречающегося элемента в массиве. Если вдруг кто не понял, пример:

Дан массив: 3 4 5 3 6 7 5 3 4 3 3 8 5 4

Тут чаще всего встречается тройка. Вот ее и надо вывести

Натолкните на идею\алгоритм, с пом.которого можно это все реализовать?

p.s. вариантом решения было такое: создать массив, размерность которого - максимально возможный элемент в массиве, затем в этот массив прибавлять по единичке, когда встречаешь из первого массива элемент. Так пройтись по массиву, и затем отсортировать второй массив по возростанию и вывести последний элемент.
Но думаю, что это малость извращение.

Comment: Это на каких олимпиадах такие задачки дают?

Comment: Яндекс. Алгоритмы

Comment: это какая? сёдня не было такой

Comment: хочешь извращаться? Да здравствуют ассоциативные массивы! )

Comment: Должно сработать:

    arr.GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(g => g.Count).First().Key

Answer (score 4):

если ничего не известно , то только сортировка и затем подсчёт повторов и выбор самого частого.

если же заведомо известно , что самый частный элемент больше чем в половине элементов то есть простой алгоритм ( догадайся , либо выгугли)

если же  заведомо известно в каком диапазоне  элементы , то можно счётчиком.

в иных случаях - иные специфические особенности.

Comment: Сортировка-то зачем? Сортировать будете в лучшем случае за NlogN, а потом еще потребуется линейное время на проход по массиву. А можно просто пройтись по массиву с подсчетом элементов в хэштаблице без какой-либо сортировки и проход по счетчикам.

Comment: a_gura допускает очень типичную ошибку, забывая о времени на поиск в хэштаблице. Если для каждого элемента массива выполнить такой поиск, а в ряде случаев еще и модификацию хэштаблицы, то количество операций будет намного больше NlogN.

В данном случае по скорости ничего быстрее сортировки не сделать. Лично на практике неоднократно убеждался в этом. Задача в общем-то типовая. На больших массивах разницу в скорости получал на порядок и выше.

Решение с хэштаблицой в ряде случаев может быть проще/удобнее по реализации, но сортировка быстрей.

Comment: Ура, в кои-то веки алгоритмическая дискуссия!

Вброшу-ка и я: но ведь вставка в hash table O(1), разве нет?

Answer (score 1):

Наиболее простой для понимания алгоритм: создание второго массива b [0, 1, 2...] для каждого из чисел и инкремент, например, b[5] при нахождении в a[47] числа 5.

Лично я могу посоветовать тебе прочитать про алгоритм Бойера-Мура. Это очень простой, маленький и быстрый алгоритм.

Comment: А если числа в исходном массиве 64-битные, какого размера собираетесь заводить массив `b`?

Comment: Это как очень простой для понимания алгоритм. Я же не говорю, что нужно использовать его всегда и везде! На мой взгляд, он подходит только для обучения.

Comment: @Platon-Efimov: вообще-то, это вариант предыдущего ответа: [сортировка подсчётом](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC).

Comment: Ага, окей, я понял, вообщем даже после создания массива нужен будет строковый алгоритм. Сразу вопрос в тему строк: что лучше: КМП или БМ??